# Multiple PHP classes in one file

Tags: php, class, caching

I have multiple PHP classes with approximately 20 functions each all in one PHP file.  Will the server store every class and every function in memory once I include this file?

Or will it only load the class and its functions once I instantiate like so?:

```
$ajax = new ajax();
```

Or will the server only cache the functions that I specifically call?:

```
$ajax->make_request();
```

I'm wondering if it is OK to have so many classes and functions housed in one single PHP file or if I should put in some type of logic that includes only the classes and functions that are required for the job.

Comment: Even if your classes and functions span a few thousand lines of text, the memory impact could be quite small to a single image manipulation, a poorly written database query handle or many other things. Weight up the hassle of including only the right classes in each file vs a touch more memory being used for a moment. The memory of the code will probably pale in comparison to the first few objects being instanciated with `= new ....` anyhow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused about how PHP works.

Every request the PHP parser, parses the requested file, e.g. `index.php`

If `index.php` `include`'s another file, PHP will the parse that file.

Once a PHP file is parsed, it is stored in memory with "byte codes" (an almost machine language), during that request.

Regardless of how many functions or classes are in a file, it will all be stored in memory for that request.

There are extensions like APC that cache these parsed byte codes in memory between requests, but they need to be added on to PHP.

It is however better (in terms of memory usage) to use auto loading for your classes.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

PSR0 is a good set of guidelines for autoloading classes:

https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

Answer (score 4):

The logic you need is called "Autoloading",
this is the process to include magicaly the class `Ajax` when the php executable hit a `new Ajax();` instruction.

This way, there is never useless classes loaded in memory.

Look at [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) and this good [ClassLoader component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader.html).

(If you only have 20 classes on your project, you don't need to add an autoloader - the profit will be very low).

Answer (score 2):

No, server by default will not cache anything unless it is set up to cache stuff with use of APC or similar extensions. So if your code uses all these classes then it would be perhaps better to put them in one file to reduce I/O. But if you do not use, separate the code into logical classes, put into separate file and use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).